# Reconhecimento de voz no php

Tags: php

Essa pergunta é de curiosidade mesmo, não estou mexendo em nada do tipo, mas no futuro quem sabe.

**Queria saber se existe algum tipo de sistema ou se é possível criar um sistema que possa fazer o reconhecimento de voz (seja para login, ou comandos quaisquer), utilizando o php.**

Se não for possível, gostaria de entender **porque** não se dá para fazer algo assim no php.

Considero o recurso de voz fascinante, e cogito, quando tiver mais propriedade e maturidade sobre o assunto, em trabalhar num sistema ou api do tipo.

Comment: http://www.speechapi.com/ e
http://voicephp.com/ e
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Relacionada : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101980/compatibilidade-do-google-speech-api

Comment: Gabriel, nesse link que você postou não tem nada de php mano. Eu até tinha visto ele antes, mas não sanou minha dúvida.

Comment: É possível fazer em php, porém inviável. No máximo, a função do PHP será na parte de login após receber os dados de áudio. Para receber o áudio precisará capturá-lo e decodificar. O PHP poderá decodificar e fazer as comparações mas para isso necessitará de alguma extensão escrita em C, JAVA, VB ou qualquer outra linguagem mais adequada.

Comment: então o php sozinho não conseguiria fazer?

Comment: @DiChrist precisará no minimo de Javascript pro microfone e Ajax com File API pra enviar o áudio pro PHP, ou seja será bem mais que PHP. Mas é provável que o reconhecimento sim poderá ser feito com PHP depois do áudio enviado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O "estado da arte" de reconhecimento de voz é bem avançado, então implementar um sistema desses do zero seria um trabalho enorme, exigiria muita pesquisa e várias pessoas trabalhando por meses ou anos. Faz mais sentido no caso chamar uma API de terceiros (que já resolveram o problema), como por exemplo https://wit.ai

Dito isso, desconsiderando performance/eficiência, não existe em teoria nada que impeça alguém de implementar um sistema de reconhecimento de voz "manualmente" em PHP (ou em qualquer linguagem). Você precisaria utilizar (ou desenvolver) uma biblioteca para ler o arquivo de audio e retornar uma stream, e então passar essa stream por algum tipo de processamento para reconhecer a fala.

Existem várias técnicas para reconhecimento de voz (modelos ocultos de Markov, DTW, Redes Neurais, etc). Esse link da wikipedia (em inglês) tem algumas informações sobre o assunto:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition#Models.2C_methods.2C_and_algorithms

Aqui está a documentação da API HTTP da wit.ai, que mencionei acima:

https://wit.ai/docs/http/20141022

Os exemplos estão em bash (usando o cURL), então você teria que reescreve-los em PHP.

Comment: Vou me aprofundar no assunto e conhecer essa ferramenta. De fato tinha em mente que tentar usar algo assim iria dar um enorme trabalho. Vou buscar conhecer mais essa ferramenta ou outra que possa ajudar nesse sentido.

Answer (score 4):

Essa pergunta já teve uma resposta aceita, eu marquei para responder e acabei não tendo tempo, mas nunca é tarde para agregar e fazer novas considerações.

> Queria saber se existe algum tipo de sistema ou se é possível criar um
>   sistema que possa fazer o reconhecimento de voz (seja para login, ou
>   comandos quaisquer), utilizando o php.

Sua pergunta ficou aberta você quis perguntar sobre um sistema que converte o que é falado em texto (transcrição) ou você quer um sistema que o usuário usa a voz para previamente gravar uma palavra e o seu sistema vai ter como base a voz/palavra falada pelo usuário para comparar e validar? São dois sistemas completamente diferentes.

Claro o Primeiro tipo de sistema é complexo mas o segundo eu arrisco em dizer que é "fácil" com poucas linhas de código em matlab eu consigo ranquear e qualificar o quão parecido é uma palavra pré gravada com uma nova.

Eu não sei exatamente datas mas desde a década de 80 é utilizado o `MFCC - Mel Frequency Cepstral Coeficientes` para encontrar padrões de fala, estamos falando em mais de 30 anos e essa técnica ainda é considerada o estado da arte para este tipo de reconhecimento (encontrar palavras pré gravadas de um dado locutor).

Para esclarecer um pouco o `MFCC` é derivado do `Cepstrum`:

```
cepstrum = IFFT(log(FFT(s)))
```

O que essa equação significa ?

Ela retorna um envelope/formantes (contorno) das frequências de um sinal no domínio da frequencia, isso nos diz de maneira consistente a forma do trato vocal no envelope do espectro.

Portanto a diferença entre MFCC com Cepstrum são as bandas de frequência igualmente espaçadas na escala [mel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_scale), o qual se aproxima da resposta do sistema auditivo humano de forma mais estreita do que as bandas de frequência linearmente espaçados utilizados no cepstrum normal.

OK temos uma maneira de capturar a forma de onda de qualquer palavra no espectro e ai como comparamos isso?

Vamos apelar para um método determinístico (métodos que não dão nenhum tratamento especial ao ruído presente nos dados, e se espera que estes dados realmente estejam de alguma forma contaminados), isso quer dizer que você vai precisar comprar "algo" pré gravado com "algo" novo seja em condições boas (sem ruídos) ou ruins (com ruídos) e mesmo assim ser capaz de determinar o quão parecido eles são, parece complexo, mas nem tanto, podemos utilizar [DTW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) - Dynamic Time Warping para comparar dois vetores com as informações dos coeficientes retornados pelo MFCC e tomar uma ação.

O método descrito aqui foi amplamente utilizado em celulares na década de 90, na função onde você associava um contato com uma voz pré-gravada tipo (Fernando) você falava no microfone "Fernando" e ele ligava para o seu contato.

Sobre fazer esse sistema em linguagem PHP tecnicamente é possível sim, pode ser mais complicado por não ter funções nativas para transformada de fourier e nem gravação com encode e decode de áudio.

Answer (score 3):

Supondo que você já entende a complexidade enorme de fazer isso em qualquer linguagem, melhor tratar das coisas que deixam isso possível ou impossível em PHP.

Dá para dividir cada programa em duas partes: a lógica e o I/O. I/O quer dizer que comunica com o programa a algo diferente: entrada e saída. Tipos de I/O comum são escrever e ler de disco, entrada de dados pelo usuário, mostrar tela de informação para o usuário etc. No caso o PHP, mesmo que não a linguagem mais rápida ou bonita, é bem capaz de fazer toda coisa de cálculo necessário para reconhecimento de voz. Os sistemas virando-se mais capaz isso menos e menos será um problema. Porém na parte de I/O precisa procurar um jeito de obter os dados de voz do usuário. É possível usar o PHP no computador sem funcionar como site, mas suponho que em uso normal não faria isso. Então terá que lidar com os meios da internet para obter os dados que precisa, que é o som da voz.

Anteriormente isso era completamente impossível: não havia sistema de entrada de voz no navegador que pude usar, exceto talvez o Flash e os applet Java. Hoje em dia porém tem o WebRTC. Precisará usar um pouco de JavaScript, mas é possível: pede pelo JavaScript acesso ao microfone, e passa essas informações para o backend que usa o código PHP para reconhecimento de voz para retornar informações para o usuário. Se tem biblioteca para reconhecimento de voz no sistema até pode acessar aquele desde PHP e poupar a você um monte de trabalho.

Então, sim, é possível, mas por causa da necessidade inevitável de ter um tipo de I/O não pode ser PHP puro. Mas sendo sincero, quem já escreveu PHP puro, se tem que produzir HTML mesmo para o usuário poder fazer qualquer coisa útil?

Comment: `quem já escreveu PHP puro, se tem que produzir HTML`: eu escrevo scripts de "php puro sem html" semanalmente para fazer coisas diversas como importar uma base dados externa, exportar minha base de dados, crawlar alguma webpage (huhg, crawler em php sucks), etc. Também tem uma infinidade de projetos php que são feito para rodar localmente: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer, https://github.com/phpmd/phpmd, https://github.com/rlerdorf/phan, https://getcomposer.org/.

Comment: eu sei dessas coisas, temos isso aqui também na empresa, mas tudo isso geralmente ainda é em função de manutenção de site.