# Alternativas para não usar o WebView

Tags: android, webview

Existem outras alternativas que não sejam o [webview](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)  do android para se usar? Estou tendo um problema que pelo que parece, uma grande quantidade de pessoas possuem que é rodar vídeos na tag [video](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) do html5.

Muitas pessoas dizem que a solução é simplesmente utilizar o [webchromeclient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html) e a mágica aconteceria sem nenhum esforço, pois bem, não funciona. Ao que parece, na versão 4.4+ do android esse componente se tornaria nativo e nas inferiores temos que seta-lo dessa maneira: `webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());`

Eu fiz diversos testes e o resultado tem sido bem frustante. Apesar do tempo que o html5 já esta no nosso meio, muitos navegadores mobiles não conseguem implementar boa parte dos recursos, ou pelo menos, implementa-los bem. O que melhor executou a funcionalidade de vídeo foi o Mozilla firefox. Tendo isso em vista, pesquisei como ele fazia isso e vi que ele utilizava de outro webview pro android, que é o [geckoview](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView).

Alguém já conseguiu utilizar esse geckoview? Como fez?

Answer (score 3):

### crosswalk

Conforme [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50811/3635) existe um projeto chamado [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org) (requer Android 4.0+)

Pra instalar: https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android.html

Suporte:

WebRTC, WebGL, Vibration API, Presentation API e WebView updates

A diferença é que ele usa WebApps, veja como criar uma aplicação (o que acho que já seria o seu caso):

https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/build_an_application.html

### GeckoView

Pra usar o GeckoView faça o seguinte:

- Baixe o `geckoview_library.zip` e `geckoview_assets.zip` no endereço https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mobile/releases/
- Extraia o conteúdo
- Abra o Eclipse (se usar Eclipse) e vá até <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Import</kbd> e o projeto da lib do GeckoView.
- Defina o GeckoView no seu projeto como dependência, tal como esta na imagem:

  [image: Library]
- Copie a pasta `asset` do `geckoview_assets.zip` para a pasta `asset` do teu app.
- Adicione `manifestmerger.enabled=true` no arquivo do teu projeto `project.properties`, a estrutura da pasta deve ficar algo como:

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Vá no layout do teu arquivo e adicione o seguinte:

  ```
  <org.mozilla.gecko.GeckoView
  android:id="@+id/geckoview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  ```
- E dentro do `mainActivity` adicione:

  ```
  GeckoView geckoView = (GeckoView) findViewById(R.id.geckoview);
  geckoView.add("http://pt.stackoverflow.com");
  ```

Se quiser um exemplos pré-prontos:

- https://github.com/mfinkle/geckobrowser
- https://github.com/fred-wang/geckobrowser