# Layout quebrado Safari8

Tags: css, safari, webkit

Olá! Estou começando no frontend e estou tendo algum probleminhas quanto a compilação de código em diferentes browsers. Desenvolvendo um header e um menu estilo Canvas me deparei com o o layout totalmente quebrado no Safari8. Usei algumas tags css de motores de renderização --webkit e afins, mas o problema persiste.

Segue abaixo o layout no Chrome e o mesmo no Safari além do código.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
header input#menu {
  display: none;
}
header .control {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
header .control span {
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #cccccc;
  display: block;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
.navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #333;
}
header .container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
header .container div.logo {
  color: #cccccc;
}
#canvas {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
}
#canvas nav.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
#canvas nav.navbar ul li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#canvas nav.navbar ul li a.link {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  color: #cccccc;
  transition: all .1s linear;
}
#canvas nav.navbar ul li a.link:hover {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="menu">
    <label class="control" for="menu" id="btn-menu">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </label>

    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
  </div>
</header>
<div id="canvas">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="link">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="link">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="link">Contato</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot Safari]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As medidas `vm` requerem Safari10, recomendo usar medidas normais, veja http://caniuse.com/#search=vm

E o Safari8 também requer que o `display: flex;` use o prefixo `-webkit-` (se bem que olhando nem estou conseguindo ver a necessidade do `flex`), de qualquer forma ficaria assim:

```
seletor {
    /*navegadores safari e chrome mais antigos*/
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;

    /*navegadores atualizados*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Recomendo que não use `vm`, neste seu caso `vm` nem parece necessário, `px`, `em` substituem perfeitamente, até talvez com `width: 10%;` consiga o resultado.

Mas se mesmo assim ainda achar que realmente precisa de `vm` então veja esta resposta tem uma alternativa ao as medidas vm em jQuery:

- [R: Estilo do app em CSS3 puro quebra ao rodar no Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50807/3635)

De qualquer forma usando os prefixo e `width: 100%` deve resolver, teste por favor:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%; /*troquei o vm aqui*/
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
header input#menu {
  display: none;
}
header .control {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  
  /*prefixos*/
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header .control span {
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #cccccc;
  display: block;
}
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
.navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
header {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #333;
}
header .container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
header .container div.logo {
  color: #cccccc;
}
#canvas {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
}
#canvas nav.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
#canvas nav.navbar ul li {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#canvas nav.navbar ul li a.link {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  color: #cccccc;
  transition: all .1s linear;
}
#canvas nav.navbar ul li a.link:hover {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="menu">
    <label class="control" for="menu" id="btn-menu">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </label>

    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
  </div>
</header>
<div id="canvas">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="link">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="link">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="link">Contato</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```